# Posting PDF file with form-data: corrupted file?

Tags: file-upload, python-requests, multipartform-data

I'm trying to upload a pdf file with form-data to a server. The upload works but the file gets corrupted for some reason (I can't open the uploaded version). Here's my code:

```
post_url = 'https://myposturl'
headers = {
  'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8; boundary=MyBoundary'
}
with open('./myfile.pdf', 'rb') as f:
  body = f'--MyBoundary\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="myfile.pdf"\r\nContent-Type: application/pdf\r\n\r\n{f.read()}\r\n--MyBoundary--\r\n'
res = s.post(post_url, headers = headers, data = body)
```

I thought it was coming from the `\r\n`, I tried a `replace('\n', '\r\n')` on the `f.read()` output but it didn't work.

Also, when using https://httpbin.org to check the POST request, I get `\\\\r\\\\n` for each new line in the pdf binary data. I'm wondering if this is normal, maybe that could help.

Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

With `requests` it can be done a bit easier.

```py
import requests

post_url = 'https://myposturl'
files = {'file': open('./myfile.pdf', 'rb')}
r = requests.post(post_url, files=files)
```

[More docs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file).

The reason you get corrupted file is probably because you're setting headers and body manually. `requests` usually sets theses things implicitly, so you should not break this concept and follow official guides.

Comment: I have to go through headers because of other constraints though. I think it comes for the \r\n conversion, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Yes I did, expect in my case it causes other issues, and I'd rather deal just with the headers nightmare for now 